# import/export product in italian

Tags: magento-1.7, import, export

I am new to magento and I have two questions to ask you, I hope you can help me.

In fact I have to take care of a existing website.this website is in French and English and I have to add a view to put up Italian.

So I downloaded the Italian pack.
I have to translate a nearly 300 products.
I saw that I could do it by importing a CSV file.
But how do I do that knowing only the name and description should be updated to the Italian view.

for the csv files that are in the "Local" folder of the new Italian language, they told me it missing some of translations.so how do I identify missing translations?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing from Italy ;)

You can identify the missing translation by comparing the us_US files with it_IT ones.

You should check the difference in number of rows.
If the english versione has more rows of the italian one you have to add and translate the missinig one.
Also some lines of the italian files may be not translated but in this case you have to read the whole file and do a visual search.

I dont understard your question about the product name and descriptio can you clarify ?

edited after your comment.

To translate all 300 product you can use the standard dataflow import.
write a simple file like the following example:

```
store,websites,sku,name,short_description,description,...
it,base,product_sk,"nome prodotto","descrizione breve","descrizione",...
```

If the dataflow found and existig product it will update the product instead of creating a new one.

In order to update the italian name just write in the "store" column the code of the italian storeview.

Please note that additional columns may be required and is omitted int this sample.

Comment: thank you for your help.If i understand the first line is the name of field and other lines are datas.but how can i to find the name of field for italien view?in my test when i use export profiles,and i chose the english view, in colum store,it write "default"

Comment: The name of the fields are exactly the attribute_code of the attributes you define. Please refer to the Attribute management or do an export of one product to get the full list of available columns/attribute.

Comment: Hy strauss if you find my info useful please check the answer as "answered" and/or upvote it. Thank you..

Comment: thank you.OK how do I?

Comment: you should have a check icon on the left of my anser near the up arrow the 0 and the down arrow..